# Is $f(x)$ Riemann integrable? Find $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

$$f(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1/n  & \mbox{if } \frac{1}{n+1}\le x < \frac{1}{n} \\
  0 & \mbox{if}\ x =0
 \end{array}
\right.$$
Is $f(x)$ Riemann integrable? 
Find $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$

My approach :

I have difficulty in calculating the integral I can prove that it is Riemann integrable

divide the interval $[0,1]$ such that $[\frac{1}{2},1]\cup[\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}]\cup[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3}]...[\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1}]$

now $m_r = M_r= 1/r$ for each $[\frac{1}{r},\frac{1}{r+1}]$
so $$L(P,f)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{r}(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1})$$

I am struck with calculation of this sum can anyone guide me how to calculate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum $\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty\,\frac{1}{r^2}$ is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) and equals $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.  The other sum $\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty\,\frac{1}{r(r+1)}$ is easy if you try to use the technique of telescopic summation.

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware of the first sum . Yes I can calculate second summation easily thanks a lot!